# UPDATE statement failed because data cannot be updated in a table that has a nonclustered columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I have a SP that does an update to a table. On that table I have a trigger. When I run the SP it gives me the following error.

> 35330 TRG_TrackDateTime  UPDATE statement failed because data cannot
>   be updated in a table that has a nonclustered columnstore index.
>   Consider disabling the columnstore index before issuing the UPDATE
>   statement, and then rebuilding the columnstore index after UPDATE has
>   completed.

Code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TRG__TrackDateTime]
ON  [Table]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @rowsUpdated int

    UPDATE Table
    SET TrackDateTime = GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED i, table t
    WHERE i.ID = t.ID
    SET @rowsUpdated=@@ROWCOUNT

    IF @rowsUpdated=0 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table
        SELECT TrackDateTime
        FROM INSERTED
    END
END
```

How do I disable and enable my indexes in the trigger?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? Sounds like 2012. Newer versions don't have this restriction.

Comment: Columnstore indexes are used in data warehouse scenarios which means they have a *lot* of data. You can't disable and re-enable indexes for each individual row. One option would be to *not* use triggers and use `GETDATE()` in the `UPDATE` statement. Another option would be to disable the index before a batch update with `ALTER INDEX .... DISABLE` and rebuild it after the batch with `ALTER INDEX .... REBUILD`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using 2014 SSMS

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool. *Clustered* columnstore indexes in 2014 are updatable. Is there a reason you're using a nonclustered index that *includes* `TrackDateTime`? If you don't want to use a clustered columnstore index, you could create a nonclustered one that *doesn't* include auditing columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That, or have a default constraint for the column. Seems a bit silly to do this using a trigger, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @TT. the default constraint will record the time of insertion, not the time of update. A *different* tracking mechanism would be preferable though. Eg writing to a separate Auditing or Tracking table the time of creation/deletion for each row

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right, silly me :-). And indeed, doing this from a trigger is kind of circuitous.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drop and create a columnstore index. Assuming your table name as 'TABLE1':

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'CSIDX_TABLE1')
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX [CSIDX_TABLE1] ON [dbo].[TABLE1];
END

/* Your UPDATE here */

CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CSIDX_TABLE1 ON [dbo].[TABLE1]
( 
    Column1,Column2
)
```